# git pull, changes made getting reverted by other colleagues

Tags: git

I'm having a puzzling issue with our Git repository. I've made explicit changes to some files,  for example queue.php in my repo:

[image]

I committed the change a while back, and pushed it to the repository.

[image]

At a8a76d4, my change was pushed to the repository.

On 2cd4666, it shows that my change was explicitly removed, but my colleague is steadfast that he never edited this file, neither did he have a conflict.

[image]

This has been a problem in the past, and it keeps happening. I'm suspecting that the developers are using a GUI and when conflicts emerge, they just click "Resolve using mine". But with this file, this seems unlikely, as there are no other changes in it.

I can't figure out why my changes are being discarded, when people claim to have never touched those files.

We are going to take a new approach on our work flow where developers are required to fork and make pull requests, but I'm still trying to understand why changes would get overridden like this.

Any ideas?

Comment: "On 2cd4666, it shows that my change was explicitly removed, but my colleague is steadfast that he never edited this file, neither did he have a conflict." Well, unless you have secret agents crawling around the office, he DID modify it, may be he just wasn't aware of it. I'd ask him to show how exactly does he check what he commits.

Comment: What's the betting it's `git add .; git commit -m "I'm going to assume I'm only commiting foo"` or equivalent

Answer (score 3):

### Git blame

If you use git blame, you can see which commit is responsible for any given line of code:

```
> git blame queue.php
...
xxxxxxx queue.php   Author    Date    47) 'queue' => 'default'
```

Then, you need only look at the commit responsible to determine how/why it was made:

```
> git show xxxxxxx
commit xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Author: Derp Diggler <email>
Date:   The date

    Unwittingly screw things up

    By the gods, we'll have no tms

diff --git ...
```

Of course, this will only confirm what you already know - that commit `2cd4666` is responsible, the rest of the problem isn't a programming issue - it's organic =).

### Or is that a file that *should* be modified

Alternatively, if `queue.php` is a file that developers are *supposed* to edit to configure their local install it shouldn't be tracked at all.

Consider instead committing a file named for example `queue.default.php` to the repository which developers *copy* to `queue.php` when initializing the application. Or, any other solution whereby it's possible for users to change the config of their application without modifying tracked files.

[Some interesting reading](http://12factor.net/) along those lines.

Comment: The queue.php config file is the same for everyone, the files that do change, for example our database.php is not tracked, but we keep deployment versions in the repo that get symlinked when we deploy with capistrano.

Comment: I know the file was edited by a developer, why he overwrote my changes, is a mystery. Even git blame shows he removed that line I added. He still admits to not having touched the file.